# How to search and replace in shell script for command line argument value

Tags: shell, sed

Im new bee to Shell script. Im trying to do search and replace for Command line argument value.

Ex: `Sh script.sh 'ID,EmpName,Address'`

In command line for $1 I have value like `ID,EmpName,Address`

Expected output : ID: chararray,EmpName: chararray,Address: chararray

Code tried

```
 Sh script.sh 'ID,EmpName,Address'
    Print 'sed -e 's/,/: chararray,/g' '"$2"''
```

Comment: Please format your code, it is hard to read currently.

Comment: John, changed the format, please have a look

Comment: Select text and use the  `{}` button above the windows to make formatting better.  (see what I have done, and make it even better)

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
echo "$2" | sed -e 's/,/: chararray,/'
```

or similar instead of:

```
sed -e 's/,/: chararray,/g' "$2"
```

As written sed thinks you are asking it to run on a file named `ID,EmpName,Address`, not on a string with that value.

Caveat: I have no idea what `hadoop` or `apache-pig` as tagged in your question are, the above is how to write the code in UNIX shell.